# Email verification in AD B2C after Signup

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am using AD B2C custom policies and I have a Business scenario that user will go through the signup (Email verification is disabled, also not able to log in). After the successful signup user need to receive an email with a **Confirm account** link. When the user clicks the link we need to enable the login and then only user can sign in. Is there any way that we can do this?